# This code is not decreasing the value by 1

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update next table named 'book' but this UPDATE code is not working

```
"UPDATE books SET Quantity=Quantity-1 Where Book_ID='$Book_ID'";
```

this code should update the books table by decreasing the value of Quantity by 1

Comment: You should look into prepared statements to make your SQL more secure.

Comment: *Which* value doesn't get decreased: do you want property `Quantity` to be one less than before or one less than the current value of some variable referenced by `$Quantity`?

Comment: I have two table one is book and another is library_user, if you are the library administrator and you added the new user who have taken book from library then while entering the new user you have to enter that which book he/she has taken from library i.e denoted by (book id) and the quantity of that book should be decreases by 1

Answer (score 5):

You need to decrease from column value, not PHP variable. Remove the dollar sign and quotes, of you have there integers.

```
UPDATE books SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 Where Book_ID = '$Book_ID'
```

Don't forget that you are vulnerable to SQL injection in WHERE clause.